# How to write VBScript to start a shortcut in a given folder?

Tags: vbscript

```
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TTS.lnk" 
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) 
oLink.TargetPath = "File\OtherFileInside\TTS.vbs"
oLink.Save 
WshShortcut.WorkingDirectory = "File\OtherFileInside"
WshShortcut.IconLocation = "notepad.exe, 0"
```

It's not working; the shortcut doesn't save with a "start in"

Comment: Are you referring to the Shortcut's configured Working Directory?

Comment: yes I am I want the shortcut to open in a certain folder so I don't need to get the folder path and just so I can know

Comment: That's not what "working directory" means. Please clarify.

Comment: Like when you go into the shortcut properties it says "open in *folder directory*"

Comment: It has "open in: (folder directory)"

Comment: I don't see that in my Shortcut Properties. I see: "Target", "Start in", "Shortcut key", "Run", "Comment". "Open File Location", "Change Icon" and "Advanced". I am running Windows 10.

Comment: My bad I meant "Start In"

Comment: I was wondering how to write the "start in" directory with vb script and how to change the shortcut logo

Comment: @dia Its didnt save with a "start in" nor a icon

Answer (score 2):

`WScript.Shell.CreateShortcut(String fileName)` creates a `WshShortcut` object. Here's the reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/xk6kst2k(v=vs.84).aspx

Your question is unclear, but if you're referring to the working directory (the directory that the target executable will use as the default location for unqualified filenames, labelled "Start in") then use `WshShortcut.WorkingDirectory`.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ae0a4aee(v=vs.84).aspx
>
> ```
> shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Example"
> ```

To set the shortcut's icon, use `WshShortcut.IconLocation`:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/3s9bx7at(v=vs.84).aspx
>
> A string that locates the icon. The string should contain a fully qualified path and an index associated with the icon. See example for more details.
>
> ```
> shortcut.IconLocation = "notepad.exe, 0"
> ```

Here's a full reference based on this screenshot:

[image]

- "Target"

  - `WshShortcut.TargetPath`
  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/594k4c67(v=vs.84).aspx
- "Start in"

  - `WshShortcut.WorkingDirectory`
  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ae0a4aee(v=vs.84).aspx
- "Shortcut key"

  - `WshShortcut.Hotkey`
  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/3zb1shc6(v=vs.84).aspx
- "Run"

  - `WshShortcut.WindowStyle`
  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/w88k7fw2(v=vs.84).aspx
- "Comment"

  - `WshShortcut.Description`
  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ybdhh477(v=vs.84).aspx
- "Open File Location"

  - Use `WshShell.Run( FileSystemObject.GetParentFolderName( shortcut.Target ) )`
- "Change icon"

  - Use `WshShortcut.IconLocation`
  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/3s9bx7at(v=vs.84).aspx
- "Advanced"

  - The "Run as administrator" option is not exposed via `WshShell`, unfortunately.

Comment: @Nik "it didn't work" is not a description of the problem. Please post the code you're using (please post actual VBScript, not a Batch File) and a screenshot of the Property sheet of the generated `.lnk` file.

Comment: Ok It make the file but didn't add the Icon or Working Directory